# How to convert .otf to .ttf (with Postscript outlines) using Fontforge scripting?

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I'm trying to use Fontforge scripting to convert an .otf font to a .ttf font (with Postscript outlines).

Default options convert to a .ttf with Truetype outlines.

I would appreciate if anyone can give some directions.

Comment: See my answer for why you can't do what you're asking about (because of incomplete knowledge of OpenType on your end), so as constructive question: why do you think you need to do this? Which problem are you trying to solve that made you think you needed to convert the font? Because [you should be asking how to solve **that** problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), not how to achieve the conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick lesson in how OpenType works: there are two flavours of OpenType: OpenType-with-CFF-Data, and OpenType-with-Truetype-Outlines

1. OpenType fonts with a CFF block use Type2 "charstring" outline definitions, which allow cubic curve modelling. They're similar to Postscript, but aren't technically Postscript. People just keep calling it that for historical reasons.
2. OpenType fonts with TrueType tables use TrueType outlines definitions, which allow for quadratic curve modelling only.

   (**2018 edit:** there are now two more types: OpenType-with-SVG-Outlines, which is **not** the same as "an SVG font", and OpenType-with-CFF2-Outlines, which is an overhaul of CFF specifically for use in OpenType rather than as an embed-agnostic outline language)

These two outline models are mutually exclusive, so you can pick whichever one you like, but not both at the same time.

Now, by convention, CFF-OT (and CFF2-OT) fonts use the `.otf` extension and TTF-OT (and SVG-OT) use the `.ttf` extension, but they're both just OpenType fonts, only differing in the CFF/TFF(/CFF2/SVG) data blocks. As such, when we talk about `otf` fonts we really mean "Postscript opentype font" (which is a misnomer because CFF uses the Type2 language, not the PostScript language), and when we talk about `ttf` fonts, we really mean "TrueType opentype font". However, an important thing to realise is that the extension does not in any way **define** the font; only its content does. We could rename the font to have a `.gif` extension and it'd still be the kind of font the content specifies. So, for font engines, the extension doesn't matter in the slightest, in the same way that an image previewer will happily open a `.jpg` file even if it has a `.png` extension.

Asking about turning an `otf`, which by convention is a "postscript" font (but again, not really, it's Type2) into a `ttf`, which by convention is a "truetype" font, and thus cannot contain "postscript" (but still, really Type2), with the added request that the `ttf` should contain "postscript outlines", doesn't make any sense: it's like asking how to convert a soft lead pencil into a hard lead pencil, but with soft lead: you're already done, you were asking how to create the thing you started with.

An Opentype font with "postscript" outlines is an `otf`.

Of course, you *can* convert a CFF font to a TrueType font, but it's a lossy conversion: it is mathematically impossible to perfectly convert cubic Bezier curves (used in Type2) to quadratic Bezier curves (used in TrueType), so you're going to end up with a font that is an approximation of the original font.

So my advice is: don't bother. Any engine that supports OpenType fonts supports both CFF and TrueType, and converting to .ttf will not do anything meaningful, while either blowing up the font size (for perceptually perfect conversion) or rendering the font incorrect with respect to the original due to lossy outline conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike.
I must admit that I was a bit confused about how font format works.

Currently working on a webfont generator, I managed to convert .OTF to .TTF using Fontforge and improve hinting using ttautohint.
But I get confused by Fontsquirrel generator that may generate a "fake" .TTF with postscript outlines. ("Expert mode", "Truetype hinting" as "keep existing")

Your answer made me understand that this file wasn't really converted to .TTF format but was just an .OTF file "relabelled" as a "fake" .TTF.

So thanks for your help.
And btw, thanks for your PHP-Font-Parser too

Comment: There's also a really simple way to see whether a font is "lying" about it's extension: open the file in a text editor, byte viewer, or whatever can load the font as "bytes", and check if the first four bytes in the file read `OTTO`. As [part of the OpenType specification](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm), OT-TTF use [00,01,00,00] as version indicator, which'll look like " .  " whereas OT-CFF use bytes [47,54,54,47], which are actually the letters "OTTO", so if you see that: that extension should be `otf` rather than `ttf` (in the loose sense of "should", of course)

Comment: As secondary advice: only use fontsquirrel to form WOFF. Reason being that [everything simply supports WOFF](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff) so we don't need any other format. WOFF is a lossless wrapper around any `otf` or `ttf` font, so you're not touching the font itself, you're simply compressing each table inside the font, for use on the web, and since everything supports it, we don't need the `otf`, `ttf`, `eot` and `svg` stuff we used to need 1~2 years ago.